# Equation spacing

Tags: formatting

Hi if I have multiple equations on each line is there a better way to space them out on the same line other than using /;?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}$\;\;\;\;\therefore \;\;\;R_{\mu \nu} -\frac{1}{2}g_{\mu \nu} R = -\kappa        T_{\mu \nu} = G_{\mu \nu} $\end{document}
```

Comment: `\quad` within math will produce space.

Comment: You might want to put them in a `\begin{equation}...\end{equation}` block rather than inline, using `\quad` for spacing as suggested. In any case you can put them on separate lines in your source file, so that you can read them there more easily.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are asking about setting an inline equation, I would suggest that starting a line with a `\therefore` or a symbol or equation is bad style. I would rephrase and use words instead of the `\therefore` symbol.

```
It is obvious therefore that, $R_{\mu \nu} -\frac{1}{2}g_{\mu \nu} R = -\kappa 
T_{\mu \nu} = G_{\mu \nu} $ \ldots.
```

I would also consider a display environment.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}

It is obvious therefore that, $R_{\mu \nu} -\frac{1}{2}g_{\mu \nu} R = -\kappa
T_{\mu \nu} = G_{\mu \nu} $ \ldots.

or use,

\begin{gather}
\begin{aligned}
\therefore \;R_{\mu \nu} -\frac{1}{2}g_{\mu \nu} R &= -\kappa  T_{\mu \nu}\\
& = G_{\mu \nu} 
\end{aligned}
\end{gather}
\end{document}
```

Comment: it's generally better to use `\begin{equation} ... \end{equation}` rather than `gather` if there's only one group.  if no equation number is wanted, use `equation*` or `\[ ... \]`, or just use `align*` to begin with.

Comment: @barbarabeeton This is the sort of my standard layout. I actually in my normal preamble I have `\let\equation\gather`, `\let\endequation\endgather` why is it generally better to use `equation`? I prefer this as it is normally easier to add to it during edits.

Comment: my understanding was that anything but `equation` requires exact matching of the `\begin` and `\end` arguments, and using `\let` to substitute hasn't been (and by policy, won't be) tested.  so if this works, it's pure, blind luck, and not guaranteed.  (in other words, if it stops working, ams won't promise to support it or patch to make it reliable.)  i'm pretty sure this is documented, though i can't point to that offhand.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks. Still curious to hear why you said it is ... better to use...

Answer (score 2):

I guess the answer to be to use `align` environment:

```
\begin{align}
    a &= b
    & c &=d
\end{align}
```

This shoulb generally work well for up to three not too wide equations.

---

As Barbara noted in the comment to this question you can use `align*` to supress the numbers, but there is another technique:

```
\begin{align}
    a &= b
    & c &=d
    \nonumber
    \\
    d + b = a + c
\end{align}
```

Which will make the `d+b = a+c` numbered. In this way you can supress number for only some of the equations you need.

Comment: i think you probably want `align*` so that there are no equation numbers.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking for different horizontal spaces to include in your inline-math, you can find many possibilities in section 11.2 of [mathmode](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/math/voss/mathmode/Mathmode.pdf). The most important are

- `a\ b`
- `a\quad b`
- `a\qquad b`
- `a\,b` and `a\;b` which you used yourself.

If you want to surround the inline math with some space to set it horzontally apart from the surrounding text, you should change the length `\mathsurround` by e.g. `\setlength{\mathsurround}{1em}`.

If you want to center this equation, the displaymath mode would be more suitable. Simply enclose the equation in `\[` and `\]` instead of `$` and `$`.

If you also want to align several of these lines horizontally, you should use the `align` environments of the `amsmath` package. (See Section 25 of [mathmode](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/math/voss/mathmode/Mathmode.pdf) for help.)